# shell script to read contain from file and grep on other file

Tags: shell

I am working on shell, I want to write one liner which will read the file contents of file **A** and execute `grep` command on file **B**.

for example, suppose there are two file

**dataFile.log**  which have following value

`abc`

`xyz`

`...` and so on

now read abc and grep on **searchFile.log** like `grep abc searchFile.log`

I have shell script for the same but want one liner for it

```
for i in "cat dataFile.log" do grep $i searchFile.log done;
```

Comment: Yes exactly i want to do that. searchFile.log contains following data
`M|21|Sid`
`F|27|Ani`
`M|24|Joe`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
grep -f dataFile.log searchFile.log
```

Note that if you want to grep as fixed string, you need `-F`, if you want to match the text in dataFile.log as regex, use `-E` or `-P`

Comment: You may need `egrep` instead, as `searchFile.log` has text like `M|21|Sid F|27|Ani M|24|Joe` (seen on comments of the question).

Comment: @fedorqui OP said `I have shell script for the same but want one liner for it` and take a look that script, I didn't see `-E` but you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep -f` option:

```
cat dataFile.log | grep -f searchFile.log
```

**Edit**

OK, now I understand the problem. You want to use every line from `dataFile.log` to grep in `searchFile.log`. I also see you have `value1|value2|...`, so instead of `grep` you need `egrep`.

Try with this:

```
for i in `cat dataFile.log`
do
   egrep "$i" searchFile.log
done
```

**Edit 2**

Following chepner suggestion:

```
egrep -f dataFile.log searchFile.log
```

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor This also requires numerous calls to `egrep` when one call using `-f` will do.

Comment: Good hint! I somehow thought it was necessary to grep line by line to get the result. I edit the question consequently.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following: it even ignores blank lines and # comments:

```
while read FILE; do if [[ "$FILE" != [/a-zA-Z0-9]* ]]; do continue; fi; grep -h pattern "$FILE"; done;
```

Beware: have not compiled this.